# Where would you ask a question about malware?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is superuser.com a good place to ask a question about a virus that was detected or is there a better suited website that uses the stackexchange engine?

Comment: superuser's fine.  unless you're trying to write one (stackoverflow) or scrubbing one off the systems you take care of at work (serverfault).  tho SU has a few already, so read through the *[virus]* tagged questions to make sure it hasn't been asked.

Comment: @~quack, your comment is a good answer, give me a chance to upvote please :P

Comment: @o.k.w thx, steal it if you like.  my meta-rep's too high already; soon i'll start seeing that *edit* link here, too, and my spelling ocd will start acting up, and.........

Comment: Yes, SU would be an ok place to ask that kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virus related questions are OK on [superuser](http://superuser.com)